# How to fill columns sequentially?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm currently developing a social media platform for a personal project. The home page of this platform shows a list of posts across 1-3 columns (depending on the screen size). The issue that I'm having is that the posts are filling the columns vertically, rather than 1 by 1. In the image below, I have created 9 posts (created chronologically 1-9) and want posts 9, 8, 7 along the top row etc:

[image: screen grab showing the current home page layout]

And the code for this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="max-w-screen-2xl p-2 mx-auto columns-1 sm:columns-2 lg:columns-3">
        <div v-for="(post, index) in posts" class="inline-block my-2 w-full">
            <Postcard :key="index" :post="post"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Also, please note that the "post cards" will vary in height with more text, and i need the cards to all have the same margin space between them (rather than each row of posts aligning) like in this image:

[image: Image showing the desired home page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until [masonry grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Masonry_layout) have wide support for most browsers, we'll have to position the elements "manually".

Consider having columns of content, distributed horizontally. We use a flex layout, so that we have full control over which elements end up in which column:

```js
const Postcard = {
  props: ['post'],
  template:
    '<div class="bg-gray-200 p-4">{{ post.id }}<br/>{{ post.content }}</div>',
};

Vue.createApp({
  components: { Postcard },
  data() {
    return {
      columns: 3,
      posts: [
        {
          id: 1,
          content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          content:
            'Ut pretium, augue et vehicula faucibus, erat ligula hendrerit mauris, quis dapibus felis lacus varius massa. Nulla mattis pellentesque nibh at lobortis.',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          content: 'Fusce hendrerit urna ut nulla dictum laoreet.',
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          content:
            'Suspendisse ultricies, nibh dignissim tempor tempor, dui justo sodales nibh, eget placerat eros enim nec nulla.',
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          content: 'Cras accumsan gravida odio.',
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          content:
            'Suspendisse sem leo, imperdiet ut tempus sed, faucibus eget tortor.',
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          content:
            'Ut interdum erat metus, vitae scelerisque leo molestie quis.',
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          content:
            'Cras placerat, ante at malesuada sagittis, diam erat euismod nisi, ac viverra tortor metus sit amet justo. Curabitur a convallis eros. Aenean sit amet volutpat augue.',
        },
        {
          id: 9,
          content:
            'Suspendisse malesuada ullamcorper nisl, et efficitur libero pretium et.',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    postColumns() {
      return this.posts.reduce((columns, post, i) => {
        const columnIndex = i % columns.length;
        columns[columnIndex] = columns[columnIndex].concat(post);
        return columns;
      }, Array(this.columns).fill([]));
    },
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.5/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-Reu6khHF2i9w9xRYM9FIpN5gnIN2NEomjN7lpCyfBtUWlOhZB78JJV3p685GNznhFov3urM2JxiDH14gwkaDMA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>

<div class="max-w-screen-2xl p-2 mx-auto flex gap-2" id="app">
  <div v-for="(posts, index) in postColumns" class="space-y-2 flex-1 min-w-0">
     <postcard :key="post.id" :post="post" v-for="post in posts"></postcard>
  </div>
</div>
```

To add the responsive behavior to emulate your `columns-1 sm:columns-2 lg:columns-3`, we can add [media query event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) [on mount](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#mounted):

```js
const Postcard = {
  props: ['post'],
  template:
    '<div class="bg-gray-200 p-4">{{ post.id }}<br/>{{ post.content }}</div>',
};

Vue.createApp({
  components: { Postcard },
  data() {
    return {
      columns: 1,
      posts: [
        {
          id: 1,
          content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          content:
            'Ut pretium, augue et vehicula faucibus, erat ligula hendrerit mauris, quis dapibus felis lacus varius massa. Nulla mattis pellentesque nibh at lobortis.',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          content: 'Fusce hendrerit urna ut nulla dictum laoreet.',
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          content:
            'Suspendisse ultricies, nibh dignissim tempor tempor, dui justo sodales nibh, eget placerat eros enim nec nulla.',
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          content: 'Cras accumsan gravida odio.',
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          content:
            'Suspendisse sem leo, imperdiet ut tempus sed, faucibus eget tortor.',
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          content:
            'Ut interdum erat metus, vitae scelerisque leo molestie quis.',
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          content:
            'Cras placerat, ante at malesuada sagittis, diam erat euismod nisi, ac viverra tortor metus sit amet justo. Curabitur a convallis eros. Aenean sit amet volutpat augue.',
        },
        {
          id: 9,
          content:
            'Suspendisse malesuada ullamcorper nisl, et efficitur libero pretium et.',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const sm = matchMedia('(min-width: 640px)');
    const lg = matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)');
    
    const updateColumns = () => {
      if (lg.matches) {
        this.columns = 3;
      } else if (sm.matches) {
        this.columns = 2;
      } else {
        this.columns = 1;
      }
    };
    updateColumns();
    
    sm.addEventListener('change', updateColumns);
    lg.addEventListener('change', updateColumns);
  },
  computed: {
    postColumns() {
      return this.posts.reduce((columns, post, i) => {
        const columnIndex = i % columns.length;
        columns[columnIndex] = columns[columnIndex].concat(post);
        return columns;
      }, Array(this.columns).fill([]));
    },
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.5/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-Reu6khHF2i9w9xRYM9FIpN5gnIN2NEomjN7lpCyfBtUWlOhZB78JJV3p685GNznhFov3urM2JxiDH14gwkaDMA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>

<div class="max-w-screen-2xl p-2 mx-auto flex gap-2" id="app">
  <div v-for="(posts, index) in postColumns" class="space-y-2 flex-1 min-w-0">
     <postcard :key="post.id" :post="post" v-for="post in posts"></postcard>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a naïve example but should illustrate the general approach. Some further points to build upon it (out of scope for this answer):

- Ensure the event listeners are removed on unmount.
- Have additional layout logic to ensure each of the columns have content distributed as expected, such as when there is an item that is of exceedingly greater or less than items around it.
- Element order (and by extension, tab order) is not the best accessibility-wise.